# hostapd in openWRT using last configuration fields instead of new one

Tags: linux, wifi, openwrt, hostapd

I'm working with hostapd in openWRT. sometimes I need to change the configuration file and activate hostapd with the new configuration. the problem is when some fields are removed in the new configuration, hostapd uses those field from the old configuration.

my big question is - could someone tell me where can I find old configuration which was saved by hostapd, or at least manipulate hostapd to use only the new configuration? I searched for it in all file system + wifi configurations
meanwhile i have to reboot OS for any new configuration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well found my answer if anyone seeing this..
in order for configuration to take effect, reload configuration is needed. 
you can do this with the command :

```
 /etc/init.d/network reload
```